# Poner icono en ventana Qt5

Tags: qt

Comienzo a aprender Qt y uno de los errores que no he podido resolver es colocar un icono a la ventana de mi programa.

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);  

  QWidget window;

  window.resize(250, 150);
  window.setWindowTitle("Icon");
  window.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icono.png"));
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Esto funciona siempre y cuando la imagen *icono.png* se encuentre en mi ruta **/home/usuario** pero quiero obtener la imagen de la carpeta raíz del proyecto sin tener que especificar la ruta al llamar la imagen. E.g.

```
window.setWindowIcon(QIcon("/toda/la/ruta/del/proyecto/iconos/icono.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Para esas cosas, Qt proporciona el mecanismo de *recursos*.

Dicho mecanismo es una manera *portable* de *incluir* archivos externos **dentro** de tu aplicación.

Se basa en el uso de *archivos de recursos*, con extensión `.qrc`, que se añaden a tu proyecto. El compilador Qt de recursos los *embebe* en tu archivo final, y pueden ser accesibles *como un archivo normal*, mediante un `QFile`, usando una *forma especial* de *ruta de acceso*: comenzando por el caracter `:`.

El tema **no es** complejo, y [la documentación de Qt5 sobre ello](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) lo detalla muy bien, con varios ejemplos.

Suponiendo que tu proyecto tenga la siguiente extructura:

> Proyecto
>   +-- proyecto.pro
>   +-- src
>   +-- builds
>   +-- images

tendrías que añadir la siguiente línea en tu `proyecto.pro`:

```
RESOURCES = proyecto.qrc
```

Ahora, creas el archivo `proyecto.qrc`, con el siguiente contenido:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
  <file>images/icono.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Creas el directorio `images` (si no lo tienes ya), y colocas ahí el icono.

Lo último, un par de cambios menores en tu código.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QIcon>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  QApplication app( argc, argv );  
  Q_INIT_RESOURCE( graphlib ); // <-- IMPORTANTE

  QWidget window;

  window.resize( 250, 150 );
  window.setWindowTitle( "Icon" );
  window.setWindowIcon( QIcon( ":/images/icono.png" ) );
  //                           ^^^ RUTA ABSOLUTA DESDE LA RAIZ DEL PROYECTO
  window.show( );

  return app.exec( );
}
```

Tras estos cambios (y puede que alguno menor, para adaptarlo a los nombres reales que uses), ya apodemos hacer

> `qmake`
>   `make`

Tu aplicación tendrá un bonito icono :-)